# How would describe a picture in terms of the degree to which a subject is visible?

Tags: word-request

How would describe a picture in terms of the degree to which a subject is visible? For example, how would you describe this picture of a bear? Something like "chest-high" comes to mind, but I'm not sure

I want an adjective or an adverb

[image]

Comment: Does this link help?

https://artpaintingartist.org/types-of-portraits/

Comment: If it were a person, _head and shoulders_.

Comment: @KateBunting [Bears have shoulders](https://idfg.idaho.gov/hunt/bear-exam/shoulder-hump); I don't see any objection to 'head and shoulders portrait of a bear'.

Answer (score 4):

For a person, I would say "head and shoulders".  But since the shoulders are relatively unimportant, I might just say "Head" or "Face".  I don't think this is necessarily a particularly tricky thing.  You can just say what is pictured.

> This photograph shows the face of a brown bear.

Comment: No. I want an adjective or an adverb

Comment: I seriously doubt English would have an adjective specifically dedicated to describing *"head-only" animal picture*. And a *shoulder-high picture* certainly wouldn't work if the animal was, say, a dolphin.

Comment: You don't "want an adjective or adverb", (or you shouldn't) You should want to communicate effectively in fairly natural English.

Comment: I guess you could say "shoulders-up" as an adjective in "shoulders-up portrait", ([example here](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShouldersUpNudity)) but it would sound weird to say "This portrait is shoulders-up."  Is there some reason you specifically want an adjective or adverb?

Answer (score 4):

In film and photography terms it's a *medium close up*:

> [image]
> https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-camera-shots/

> [image]
> https://filmlifestyle.com/medium-close-up-shot/

> [image]
>
> https://www.wix.com/blog/photography/types-of-shots

These terms can all be used as nouns and adjectives.

Comment: Note that the average native speaker has only the vaguest understanding of this. To non-photographers, a "close-up" is just "a photo where the camera is close to the face" and does not *specifically* mean that e.g. the neck is visible but the upper torso is not.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any objection to 'head-and-shoulders' as an adjective describing a picture of a bear.

[image]

Comment: Indeed - it serves as an adjective in the expression _head and shoulders portrait_.

Answer (score 1):

A coined compound word like *torso-up*, *chest-up*, or *shoulders-up* may not be standard, but would certainly be understood by the majority of natives, especially if accompanying the picture.

> a torso-up photo of a grizzly bear

I think these two options are a little better than *chest-high*, because *chest-high* is more likely to mean that the camera is at the height of the chest, or that the shot is framed with the with its centre at the height of the subject's chest.